# React: Inject common render logic from parent

Tags: javascript, code-reuse, reactjs

Let's assume i have a react component class that displays a modal dialog on a click of a button.

it can be created like this (in jsx):

```
<Modal text={"some text"}/>
```

Now, I have a bunch of component classes (let's call them Panels) that all have a function called `getMessage`, and i'd like the same behavior in all of these components: the modal dialog should show the string that returns from the call to `getMessage`.

the straight forward way to do this would be to include

```
<Modal text={this.getMessage()}/>
```

in the render() function for each such component.

Now, let's say that there is a bit more logic involved. for example,  i would only like to render this component if `getMessage` is defined and does not return `null`.

Now this is starting to look like this:

```
var Panel1 = React.createClass({
    getMessage: function() {return 'wow';},
    render: function() {
        var modal = null;
        if (this.hasOwnProperty('getMessage' && this.getMessage() !== null) {
            modal = <Modal text={this.getMessage()}/>
        }
        return (
            <div>
                {modal}
                ...all other stuff done in panel
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

This is starting to become cumbersome because I need to have this logic for each and every component class I define.

How can I achieve DRYness in this scenario so that i don't have to repeat this?

One way would be to define a utility function that contains this logic, let's call it `displayModalIfNeeded` and the call it from render. this now looks like this:

```
return (
    <div>
        {displayModalIfNeeded.call(this)}
        ....all other stuff needed in Panel
    </div>
);
```

### And now for my actual question (sorry for the long exposition):

Let's say that i have a parent component called `<Dashboard>` which has all panels as its childern:

```
<Dashboard>
    <Panel1>
    <Panel2>
    <Panel3>
</Dashboard>
```

Is there something i can write in the implementation of `Dashboard` that will entirely remove the need to specify **anything** about these modal components in each Panel?

meaning the the Panel1 implementation can now just be

```
<div>
    ...all other stuff done in panel
</div>
```

and when it's rendered as a child of `Dashboard` it will have that modal dialog and accompanying logic.

Comment: If you're in charge of these components rendering the modal, don't you know if the `getMessage` is defined or not? The if/else clause seems redundant. Either it's defined or not, if not don't even include the modal in those components. Other than that, if `getMessage` returns a null message the modal should not render thus having the display logic in itself.

Comment: @HenrikAndersson these Panels can be written by other people, as a kind of plugins. if the Panel writer wants to define a message they can and if not they don't have to

Comment: I guess - two years later. I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a wrapper component with the `children` prop. Your parent component would look like this:

```
<Dashboard>
    <ModalWrapper text={msg1}>
        <Panel1 />
    </ModalWrapper>
    <ModalWrapper text={msg2}>
        <Panel2 />
    </ModalWrapper>
    <ModalWrapper text={msg3}>
        <Panel3 />
    </ModalWrapper>
</Dashboard>
```

Now all your conditional logic can be placed in `ModalWrapper`. Where your question has "....all other stuff needed in Panel", use `this.props.children`. e.g.

```
var ModalWrapper = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        var text = this.props.text;
        return (
            <div>
                {text ? <Modal text={text} /> : null}
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: I need the people that write the different panels to control the getMessage text, so i cannot inject it from above